# What are pickle, cPickle, and pickling in keras model?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, data-mining

I want to save full keras model. But in their documentation, they recommended not to use pickle or cPickle to to save a keras model.
I am not clear about the two terms.
What are they and why use or not use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) is python's persistence package; I.E. it's how you save a trained model out of memory and onto disk, so that you can load it up into a different program later.

Cpickle is Pickle, but written in C instead of Python. C is way faster than Python, so lots of libraries have a C equivalent for optimisation.